# Positioning of nodes and text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I got stuck on my diagram. Here is what i got:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, positioning, shapes}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text centered, draw=black]%minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text centered, draw=black]%minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, text centered, draw=black]%minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (dec1) [decision, below=1 of start] {a=b?};
\node (io1) [io, below left=2 of dec1] {gib gleich aus};
\node (io2) [io, below right=2 of dec1] {gib ungleich aus};
\node (end) [startstop, below left=2 of io2] {Stop};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1.west) node[above] {ja}-|(io1);
\draw [arrow] (io1)|-(end);
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east) node[above] {nein}-|(io2);
\draw [arrow] (io2)|-(end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, how can i position the text on the arrows (ja and nein) on the end of the horizontal line before it goes down? 
And this line:

```
\node (io2) [io, below right=2 of dec1] {gib ungleich aus};
```

lets me position one node relativ to another, but can i say, that i want it 1 below and 3 to the right instead of 2 in both directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `-|` or `|-` path construction, the position at the corner (where the line goes negative in your case) is `0.5`. So you can do

```
\draw [arrow] (dec1.west) -|(io1) node[pos=0.5,above right]{ja};
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east)  -|(io2)node[pos=0.5,above left]{nein};
```

And you can say

```
 \node (io1) [io, below left=1cm and 2cm of dec1] {gib gleich aus};
```

where the first distance in `below left=1cm and 2cm` is the vertical distance and the second one is the horizontal one. You can also set `node distance=1cm and 2cm`.

BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, text centered,draw=black},%minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,
io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text centered, draw=black},%minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
decision/.style={diamond, text centered, draw=black},%minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (dec1) [decision, below=1 of start] {a=b?};
\node (io1) [io, below left=1cm and 2cm of dec1] {gib gleich aus};
\node (io2) [io, below right=1cm and 2cm of dec1] {gib ungleich aus};
\node (end) [startstop, below left=1cm and 2cm of io2] {Stop};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (io1)|-(end);
\draw [arrow] (dec1.west) -|(io1) node[pos=0.5,above right]{ja};
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east)  -|(io2)node[pos=0.5,above left]{nein};
\draw [arrow] (io2)|-(end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With

```
\draw [arrow] (dec1.west) -|(io1) node[pos=0.5,above]{ja};
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east)  -|(io2)node[pos=0.5,above]{nein};
```

and the above-mentioned `node distance`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, text centered,draw=black},%minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,
io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text centered, draw=black},%minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
decision/.style={diamond, text centered, draw=black},%minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (dec1) [decision, below=1 of start] {a=b?};
\node (io1) [io, below left=of dec1] {gib gleich aus};
\node (io2) [io, below right=of dec1] {gib ungleich aus};
\node (end) [startstop, below left=of io2] {Stop};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (io1)|-(end);
\draw [arrow] (dec1.west) -|(io1) node[pos=0.5,above]{ja};
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east)  -|(io2)node[pos=0.5,above]{nein};
\draw [arrow] (io2)|-(end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

I am also wondering if you wanted to use

```
\node (dec1) [decision, below=1 of start] {$a=b$?};
```

i.e. math mode for the equation `a=b`.

Comment: This works flawlessly, but when i saw you answered, i was not surprised. You, UnDead Cat, are really amazing. I love your answers, because there ist always information which exceeds the question. And explanations, which are comprehensible so that one learns really what is going on and how to proceed in the future. Thanks for the info about tikzstyle. And i had a greater b in the node first, which required the math mode.